# split or separate this list wherever there is an empty list `[]` using python

Tags: python

I want to split or separate this list wherever there is  an empty  list `[]`

Sample list:

```
lists = [['I'], ['speak'], ['english'], [], ['I'], ['speak'], ['spanish'], [], ['I'], ['speak'], ['Hindu']]
```

Desired output:

```
lists = [
[['I'], ['speak'],['english']],
[['I'], ['speak'],['spanish']],
[['I'], ['speak'],['Hindu']],
]
```

How do I achieve this?

I've tried:

```
new_list = []
for I in range(len(lists)):
    temp_list = []
    if lists[i] != []:
        temp_list.append(lists [i])
    new_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to achieve this as:

```
from itertools import groupby
my_list = [['I'], ['speak'], ['english'], [], ['I'], ['speak'], ['spanish'], [], ['I'], ['speak'], ['Hindu']]

new_list = [list(l) for i, l in groupby(my_list, bool) if i]
```

where `new_list` holds:

```
[
    [['I'], ['speak'], ['english']], 
    [['I'], ['speak'], ['spanish']], 
    [['I'], ['speak'], ['Hindu']]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
new_list = [[]]
for item in lists:
    if item:
       new_list[-1].append(item[0])
    else:
        new_list.append([])
```

result:

```
[['I', 'speak', 'english'], ['I', 'speak', 'spanish'], ['I', 'speak', 'Hindu']]
```

Answer (score -1):

as you can see a way to solve the problem is [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-list-into-lists-by-particular-value/) , you can use a  Method that includes :

Using list comprehension + zip() + slicing + enumerate()

where you first split list into lists by particular value

```
size = len(test_list) 
idx_list = [idx + 1 for idx, val in
            enumerate(test_list) if val == 5]
```

and then create a new one

```
res = [test_list[i: j] for i, j in
        zip([0] + idx_list, idx_list + 
        ([size] if idx_list[-1] != size else []))]
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28228974)

Comment: Done, I just Edited to be more helpful @MuhammadUsman